# Edit text not taking background as transparent

Tags: java, android

I am setting the following to an edit text as bg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#A4A4A4" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- main color -->
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My edit Text is nested in a `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` like:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
  <EditText
          android:id="@+id/email"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_txt"
          android:hint="@string/reg_email"
          android:imeOptions="actionNext"
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:paddingEnd="10dp"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingRight="10dp"
          android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Which renders like:

[image]

The desired behavior is rendering only a line at the bottom, which covers the entire width of this element.

[image]

Comment: I thought this type of rendering was dependent on the version of Android you are running. I.e. Lollipop vs. KitKat vs. JellyBean etc... What version are you using in order to try this out?

Comment: Yes that is true, if you are setting it up in a theme. But if you are explicitly supplying a background element, it will override all values.

Comment: The best way is to use themes and avoid using backgrounds.

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution, considering your advise?

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, I figured it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#AAAA" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

As per what Norton Commented above, I have come up with the following:

```
<style name="edit_box">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#AAA</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/edit_text_cursor</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_edit_txt</item>
    </style>
```

It works like a charm and I like the idea of defining this at one place and using it everywhere.